# How to submit a bug report to the Sharepoint 2010 Product team?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I believe I have found a bug in Sharepoint 2010, and would like to submit this to the product development team.

I tried to use Microsoft Connect, but it seems that Sharepoint 2010 is not in the active list of products that are receiving Feedback.

Does this mean that the bug reporting stage for MOSS (Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server) 2010 is over? And it is no longer possible to submit product bugs?

Is there another channel of general public communication with the product team? I have an MSDN subscription if this helps.

Comment: I see the same issue.  There must be a way.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesnt in directory.
http://connect.microsoft.com/directory/business-software/

Answer (score 0):

There is an entry for Sharepoint Community under Business Software. And they are accepting bugs as well.

Comment: Aha, this looks like the right entry point. Thanks a lot Zecougar.

Comment: I don't see an entry for SharePoint 2010 under Business Software category.  Can you provide the link where you see it?